# Why I cant create a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Im starting with mysql, but it doesnt allow me to create a simple table. It says: "A table must have at least one visible column".
[image]

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBejY.png):

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyLYP.png):

Comment: Add the statements as text not as screenshot

Comment: You do not specify any column an a table without columns oes not makes sence

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE` statement must have at least one column definition, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html

Comment: I doubt if the error message could be any clearer..

Answer (score 0):

Columns must be added to the table during its creation

try

```
CREATE TABLE LOCURA (`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: but in the sql course im following, the "teacher" just type this:

Comment: A table is a collection of columns and rows. You need at least one column.
Maybe th teacher forget that , if you like to share this lesson you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

There need to be at least one column when creating

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
column1 datatype,
column2 datatype,
column3 datatype,
....
);
```